# Excel strLookup Help (Dynamnic worksheet value)

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

Good day
I am trying to run a vlookup from a different workbook using strLookup.
It works great if the workbook and worksheet names are static; however i need to insert a dynamic sheet name from a string i defined earlier in the macro and it doesnt work

I tried the below

This Works:

```
strLookup = "'C:\Users\hayekn\Desktop\AR Reports\0MENACA Working File\AR Working File\1- Macro AR reporting\Delta\[test.xlsx]40'!A:B"
```

These dont work (trying to change the worksheet name "40" to a dynamic value defined earlier (DailyWeek -1)

```
strLookup = "'C:\Users\hayekn\Desktop\AR Reports\0MENACA Working File\AR Working File\1- Macro AR reporting\Delta\[test.xlsx](Dailyweek -1)'!A:B"

strLookup = "'C:\Users\hayekn\Desktop\AR Reports\0MENACA Working File\AR Working File\1- Macro AR reporting\Delta\[test.xlsx]Dailyweek -1'!A:B"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

My Entire Code Below:

```
Dailyweek = Workbooks("AR Reporting Tool.xlsm").Worksheets("Reports").Range("G30")

Dim sh As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
For Each sh In Worksheets

If sh.Name Like (Dailyweek - 1) Then flg = True: Exit For
Next

If flg = True Then
    'MsgBox "Found!"
    wbk4.Sheets("UAE").Activate
    With wbk4.Sheets("UAE")
    Set clDest = .Range("N2")
    Set clLookup = .Range("A2")
    strLookup = "'C:\Users\hayekn\Desktop\AR Reports\0MENACA Working File\AR Working File\1- Macro AR reporting\Delta\[UAE FM.xlsx](Dailyweek -1)'!A:B"
    End With

    If clLookup.Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then
    rws = Range(clLookup, clLookup.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Set clDest = clDest.Resize(rws, 1)
    End If
    clDest.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & clLookup.Address(False, False) & "," & strLookup & ",2,0),0)"
    clDest.Value = clDest.Value ' Convert to value

else
  msgbox "Doesnt exist"
end if
```

Comment: Needs more code.  It's hard to tell what you're actually doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to construct your string properly.
Something like this perhaps?

```
strLookup = "'C:\Users\hayekn\Desktop\AR Reports\0MENACA Working File" _
    & "\AR Working File\1- Macro AR reporting\Delta\[test.xlsx]" _
    & (Dailyweek -1) & "'!A:B"
```

Comment: Sometimes the smallest things can make one look so stupid :) Thank you so much, worked perfectly

Comment: @user3800275 That can be improved through practice and experience. Btw, big things were from small things and most of the time, small things are what matters.

Comment: Thanks to people like you who come forth to help others, appreciated !!

Comment: @user3800275 You can do the same :) Just drop by here if you have time to spare and start answering other peoples questions.